# PHP imap_body gets truncated

Tags: php, imap, gmail-imap

Im trying to download and synchronize imap email but when I download certain messages with imap_body the string gets truncated, it doesn't retrieve the entire raw message like I expect it to, am I missing something? This is the code I got:

```
$raw_headers = imap_fetchheader($imap, $msgno);
$message = $raw_headers;
$message .= imap_body($imap, $msgno);
echo $message;
```

The last part of some of the messages where the attachment goes its truncated, like this, this particular message actually has 2 attachments but it only shows a portion of one, can someone please help me figure this out:

```
HEADERS GO HERE

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------_=_NextPart_001_01CB2F48.59B2C620
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----_=_NextPart_002_01CB2F48.59B2C620"

------_=_NextPart_002_01CB2F48.59B2C620
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
PLAIN CONTENT GOES HERE
------_=_NextPart_002_01CB2F48.59B2C620
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
HTML CONTENT GOES HERE

------_=_NextPart_002_01CB2F48.59B2C620--

------_=_NextPart_001_01CB2F48.59B2C620
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name="HPHS burnett,gJul14.xls"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Description: HPHS burnett,gJul14.xls
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="HPHS burnett,gJul14.xls"

0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPgADAP7/CQAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAkAAAAAAAAAAA
EAAAjAAAAAEAAAD+////AAAAAJIAAACRAAAA////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problems with imap_body, so i tried instead saving the body to file and echo file contents using **imap_savebody**, which worked fine for me. 
Hope it works for you.

Ref: [imap_savebody](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-savebody.php)

Comment: I would like to be able to save the entire raw message, with imap_savebody I have to still figure out which part to get...

Comment: Omg! calling this function without a part number will get the entire message without any problems!!